# Debug Source Code while Running UnitTests

Tags: angular, unit-testing, debugging, jasmine

I have a background as Java dev and there I could use breakpoints in my SourceCode and run UnitTests to hit them. I'm trying the same now in an Angular/Typescript environment but I can only hit breakpoints in my test code.

Source Code:

```
1) export class SomeClass {
2)   someMethod() {
3)*    doit;
4)   }
5) }
```

- Breakpoint not hit

Test Code:

```
1) describe('SomeClass', () => {
2)   it('test someMethod()', () => {
3)     SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass();
4)*    someClass.someMethod();
5)   }
6) }
```

- Breakpoint hit

My preferred editor is Visual Studio Code but I'm also happy if this would work in IntelliJ/Webstorm IDE.

The package versions are:
- Angular 5.2.5
- jasmine 2.8.0
- jasmine-core 2.8.0
- karma 3.0.0
- karma-chrome-launcher 2.1.1
- karma-cli 1.0.1
- karma-jasmine 1.1.1

Comment: With IntelliJ you can place a breakpoint and run the debug mode, which will work. Otherwise, you can write `debugger;` where you want your code to stop, and finally, in the dev tools of your browser, you can open the source code and put breakpoints directly in it (e.g. in Chrome, F12, `Source` tab, Ctrl + P to open the desired file)

Comment: Have you tried https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=msjsdiag.debugger-for-chrome already? I'm quite happy with it.

Comment: @trichetriche Yes this works with Intellij. Don't know why my other tests didn't stop in the source code when I tried it. I already use the browser solution but for that you need a running app and I want to simply debug into a service on UnitTest-Level.

Comment: @ChatterOne I already have that installed but I'm want to debug my services on UnitTest Level not when the app is running in Chrome.

Comment: @CodeChimpy no you don't need a running app ; when you test, you have a browser that is ran, either a casual browser (default) or a headless. With a casual one, a test app will open, and you will be able to put breakpoints in both the spec and angular files. That's how I debug most of my apps, and I don't have running apps while I test :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way i do it, is I run my test is watch : `ng test --watch true` and then add a debug

- Start karma on my browser: `http://localhost:9876/`
- hit the debug option on the right or, directly got to `http://localhost:9876/debug.html?`
- then, inside the debug open the debugger, and add breakpoints in the
  code and/spec

Comment: I'm using ChromeHeadless to run the tests and I want to debug on UnitTest-level, not with a running App.

Comment: The method above is for Unit test, not app level (i assume by App level, you mean e2e). When you do that, this is just testing a `spec` file.  Also, this will run in `CHromeHeadless`, the only reason it will launch in chrome browser is because usually `--remote-debugging-port=9222` is set. If this is not set the Chrome wont open. So, IRL, you will test with hedaless, but for debugging you can still use Chrome