# Is there any way to use VS Code Debugger for Chrome inside Jasmine spec unit testing?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, visual-studio-code, karma-jasmine, vscode-debugger

I'm trying to set breakpoints inside specific parts of my *specs* to have a detailed step by step view of processes not being reached by my tests.

I've tried using **Debugger for Chrome** VC Code's extension, but the debug process just doesn't seem to work.

The breakpoints look unavailable and the test run like they didn't exist.

[image]

Maybe is it something on my config? Am I doing something wrong? Or it just can't be done?

Jasmine-Karma is running on localhost:9876 and here is my 
 launch.json:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
      "url": "http://localhost:9876",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
    }
  ]
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Do you run them with --watch set to true?
Have a look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53172966/2435263) for debugging with Chrome/ ChromeHeadless

Comment: Yeah, I use --watch true. Thanks for your answer and the link provided, but it doesn't really satisfy my doubts, as I was looking for a solution related to VS Code extension Debugger for Chrome. :/